# Calling member methods of a class on Data from another class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, function-pointers, vtable

I have a (non-copyable and non-movable) abstract base class `mesh` with some derived ones `mesh1, mesh2, ...` which I have no control over (code from external library). And I want to create a class `genMesh` which applies (the virtual member functions) `mesh1::update(), mesh2::update() ...` on user input to its data. Here is a minimal example of what I'm looking for.

```cpp
struct mesh
{
    int m = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    
    mesh() {}
    mesh(const mesh&) = delete;
    mesh(mesh&&) = delete;
    mesh& operator=(const mesh&) = delete;
    mesh& operator=(mesh&&) = delete;
    virtual ~mesh(){}
};

struct mesh1 : public mesh
{
    int k = 1;
    virtual void update()
    {
        cout << "mesh1 : " << k << " " << m << endl;
    }
};

struct mesh2 : public mesh
{
    int k = 2;
    virtual void update()
    {
        cout << "mesh2 : " << k << " " << m << endl;
    }
};

// What the generic class would look like
struct genMesh : public mesh
{
    int k = 5;
    virtual void update()
    {
        cout << "meshGen : " << k << " " << m << endl;

        // Create a mesh1 object, copy data from "this" to it, call update, and copy back the data
        // Using mesh1 as a blackBox
        mesh1* m1 = new mesh1();
        memcpy(m1, this, sizeof(mesh));
        m1->m = 3;
        m1->update();
        memcpy(this, m1, sizeof(mesh));
        cout << "meshGen : " << k << " " << m << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto g = new genMesh();
    g->update();

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this does not work because `memcpy` will override the vtable of `this` (the genMesh object).

I know that the proper solution to this problem is to make `mesh1, mesh2, ...` virtual children of `mesh` and make it so `genMesh` inherits from them all, but I'm trying to give the user the ability to choose which "update()" methods (from a predefined set of classes) will be called at runTime.

Is there any way to do this? (Up to C++17)

You can find the minimal example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/0NnvvwGWv)

Comment: What do you mean by `trying to give the user the ability to choose which "update()" methods (from a predefined set of classes) will be called at runTime`? Will the user be pressing any button(on-screen) or any key from the keyboard?

Comment: @LinuxGeek will be through a configuration file; something like this: `updates: (mesh1, mesh2)`.

Comment: its not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Instead of inheritance you can just have a `mesh` and several `update1(mesh&)`, `update2(mesh&)` and let the user choose which update function to use. You could put them in some container also

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I agree, but as I said, I have no control over the classes; and their library was heavily based on OO design. So I have to remedy that now :)

Comment: if `mesh1::update()` and `mesh2::update()` can be applied to `genMesh` data, then can be assumed that all the `update()` methods work on common data of base class `mesh`?

Comment: @MatG Yes, these update functions will be mostly compatible and work on common data from mesh class

Comment: `memcpy(m1, this, sizeof(mesh));` scares the <expletive deleted> out of me.

Comment: @user4581301 Well the copy from m1 to this is much more horrifying, but I'm desperate here :)

Comment: @Elwardi The purpose of `genMesh` is just to overload the `update()` method? Subclasses `mesh1` etc.. can be constructed from an instance of base class `mesh`?

Comment: @MatG; exactly; because I'll just have a pointer to a mesh object, and call update from there.

Comment: @Elwardi does `mesh` have any `private` fields?

Comment: @passing_through yes it does have some.

Comment: @Elwardi If `mesh1` can be constructed from an instance of `mesh`, so can be constructed also from an instance of `genMesh`; on the other end since you control `genMesh`, you can import data from `mesh1`. If this is true there's no need for `memcpy`.

Comment: No copy constructors unfortunately. That's why I'm memory copying

Comment: @Elwardi actually, I asked a bad question. Is there any `mesh` state we cannot take out? E.g. even by getters.

Comment: @passing_through Yes, mesh does not expose all of its private/protected members

Comment: @Elwardi seems pretty sad. Are `mesh1` and `mesh2` classes also unmodifiable for you? Unlike `genMesh`.

Comment: @passing_through yes; genMesh is my class, the others are external library code. But thanks for taking a try on this